# Closing old answered questions as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I agree with [closing old off-topic questions](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/576/close-old-off-topic-questions), but in this case the question is answered: [In an AC circuit, where does hot end and neutral begin?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/in-an-ac-circuit-where-does-hot-end-and-neutral-begin)

What is the point of closing it?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the scope of a stack might change a bit, causing older questions to become off topic. Closing them prevents folks from asking similar (off topic) questions, and using the old question as precedent for why their new question should not be closed.

When questions have become off topic, but have already been answered. I think the normal course of action is to lock the question, as having historical significance.

[image]

However, in this case, I don't believe the question is off topic.  I'm pretty sure we've allowed questions about electrical theory, but maybe I'm wrong.